# php : Parse json on Google app engine

Tags: php, json, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

I use below code to fetch an url, this works successfully, It returns an json data

```
$url =  "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$access_token;


    function fetch_url($url){

        import java.net.URL;
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;

        $java_url = new URL($url);
        $java_bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader($java_url->openStream()));

        while (($line = $java_bufferreader->readLine()) != null) {
            $content .= $line;
        }

        return $content;
    }

    // Sample usage:
    $friends = fetch_url($url);
```

when i echo $friends I get the below json code,

{

```
   "id": "100003185423323",
   "name": "hnu Chid",
   "first_name": "hnu",
   "last_name": "Chid",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/ilovaddddd",
   "username": "ilddddd",
   "education": [
      {
         "school": {
            "id": "182225911846032",
            "name": "Sunean"
         },
         "type": "High School"
      },
      {
         "school": {
            "id": "105504952817559",
            "name": "Sathya University"
         },
         "type": "College"
      }
   ],
   "gender": "female",
   "timezone": 5.5,
   "locale": "en_US",
   "verified": true,
   "updated_time": "2012-09-18T18:37:57+0000"
}
```

I cant use json decode on GAE,When i try to json decode i get server error, is there any other way to parse it on php , please help me.

Comment: Which error? post all the details.

Comment: I just get Google Server error,if i add the line $data =json_decode($friends, true);

Comment: How are you running PHP on AppEngine? It's Python, Java and Go only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure that json_decode exists (is enabled).

```
<?php
if (function_exists('json_decode')) {
    echo "json_decode functions is available.<br />\n";
} else {
    echo "json_decode functions is not available.<br />\n";
}
?>
```

2. Use try catch to catch parsing errors.

```
<?php
try {
     $response = json_decode($friends, true);
     print_r($response);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
     echo 'Caught exception: ',  $ex->getMessage(), "<br/>\n";
     var_dump($friends);
}
?>
```

3. Read more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Also try to validate JSON response here if function is OK. 
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
I've tried the posted one, it looks valid.
But I suggest you might change something for security reasons.

Comment: as he said in comments on my code, he's getting NULL. So the JSON is probably malformed, therefore I give you a +1!

Comment: It is not malformed ... i get output something like stdClass Object ( [education] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ........